# Is a cast int the same as an ordinary int

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm trying to insert a value into a JDBC, I'm getting a value from a combo box in which I have to cast to an int but the query isn't recognizing it as an int? It prints out to console as a number.

Here's a sample of code that best replicates the problem.

I've tried turning the input to a string and then parsing it, but it still won't recognize it. Its like it won't recognize the int.
I'm a bit stumped.
Thanks

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class AddingItemToComboBox implements ActionListener{

    JButton click = new JButton("Click me");
    JComboBox qty = new JComboBox();

    public AddingItemToComboBox(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        panel1.setSize(500,500);   

        click.addActionListener(this);
        qty.setBounds(10,270, 150, 20 );
        qty.setSize(80,30);
        qty.addItem(1);
        qty.addItem(2);
        qty.addItem(3);
        panel1.add(qty);
        panel1.add(click);
        frame.add(panel1);

        frame.setSize(300, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if(e.getSource() == click){

            int quan  =  (int)qty.getSelectedItem();    
            System.out.println(quan);

            //Connection to database
                    // Here is the problem "quan"
            con.insertProduct(qaun);



        }

    }
    public static void main(String[] args){

        AddingItemToComboBox aic = new AddingItemToComboBox();
    }

}
```

Error:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    qaun cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: Your code and problem doesn't appear to have anything to do with JDBC.  Can you simplify the code and the question to just the portion you are having trouble.

Answer (score 3):

Your variable is `quan` wheras you are using `qaun`

Look at the `con.insertProduct(qaun);`

The compile error shows you this clearly

Error: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: **qaun** cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: Makes as much sense as the question.

Comment: Typoed my original response.. probably what the OP did :-)

Comment: Wouldn't the compiler detect this error and prevent it compiling.  It shouldn't be detected at runtime unless you have generated byte code.

Comment: Thanks, it's been a long day

Comment: He never fully compiled it but still tried to run it. Probably using Eclipse.

Comment: The question suggests it compiles as he states it prints the value as a number.

Comment: It occurs to me that the OP is using eclipse which allows you to run programs which don't compile.  This is very bad idea IMHO.  Doing this just delays problems until as late as possible, maximising the cost of fixing those bugs.

Comment: I think Eclipse does some kind of incremental compiling where your code runs until you hit the compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

> It prints out to console as a number

This code is the same as

```
int quan  =  (int)qty.getSelectedItem();    
System.out.println(quan);
```

is the same as

```
System.out.println(Integer.toString(quan));
```

There is no way to print a number as an int as your console can only display characters so it must turn it into text.